# how to add a "Select a specialty" option to selection list, Sharepoint JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Hi' I m displaying SharePoint list data in a selection list as follows.
But I want to insert a default drop down selection as Select a Specialty. eg -  default when the page get loads eh drop down will show "Select a Specialty", then the other options from SP list 
can someone please help me.

```
function getSpecialtydata() {
    var specialtylist = web.get_lists().getByTitle("SpecialtySPlist");
    context.load(specialtylist)
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name="Title" />' +
                             '<Value Type="Text">ff</Value></Neq></Where></Query></View>');

    items = specialtylist.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(items);
    context.executeQueryAsync(OnQuerySuccsess, onQueryFails)

}

function OnQuerySuccsess(sender, args) {

        var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
        var selectListBox = document.getElementById("speciltySelect");
        if (selectListBox.hasChildNodes()) {
            while (selectListBox.childNodes.length >= 1) {
                selectListBox.removeChild(selectListBox.firstChild);
            }
        }
        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var selectOption = document.createElement("option");
            var oListItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
            selectOption.value = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Title');
            selectOption.innerHTML = oListItem.get_item('Title');
            selectListBox.appendChild(selectOption);
    }

}

    <select id="speciltySelect" style="width: 165px" onchange="val()" >
            <option></option>              
         </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the dropdown with the following and append other values to this.

```
<select id="speciltySelect" style="width: 165px" onchange="val()" >
<option disabled selected>Select a Speciality</option>
        <option></option>              
     </select>
```